# Bot framework V4 -bot behaving differently in channel

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a bot that I have side-loaded into teams. In a direct conversation, the bot behaves exactly as I intended, responding to commands that are parsed through LUIS. In the teams channel, it is as if the bot is hitting a cached endpoint, and behaving as if the code changes I've made don't exist.
Running the bot in the web test console functions as expected.
Is there some kind of caching that may be interfering?

Comment: Are you mentioning the bot using @BotName?  In a channel you must @mention the bot whereas in 1:1 chat you do not.

Comment: Yes. The bot responds, just not in the same way that it does in a direct chat

Comment: What do you mean by not the same way?

Comment: In direct chat, I get the expected answer, in a channel, I get my default "Don't know what you're talking about" response.

Comment: this is because the @mention is in the text of the question, take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-channel#-mentions